# Visualizing signal detection indices in r

Tags: r, signal-detection

I was wondering if any of you could help with how I can somehow plot result from a signal detection analysis in r? I have used the psycho package and calculated dprime, beta, aprime, bppd and c for all participants in two conditions. But I'm not quite sure how to report the result in an proper manner. I would like to have som pretty intuitive visuals, but I'm not sure what they should be or how to compute them. I hope you can help :-D

I was thinking of doing some kind of distribution plots, but I'm pretty new to doing signal detection theory - analyses, so I don't know what makes sense.
I have used this guide to compete the indices: neuropsychology.github.io/psycho.R/2018/03/29/SDT.html - and would love some visuals similar to theirs perhaps

I'm sorry if it seem like a stupid question, but I'm pretty new to this world, so I just want to be better and hopefully learn :-D

Comment: The best way to display a distribution of real number values is with a density plot. You could add color for the two different conditions. Another possibility would be a box & whiskers plot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+groups+density+plot

Comment: thank you! I will look into this :-D